# Should I hard-wrap SVN commit messages

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, commit-message

In the Git user community it's a widely adopted practice to hard-wrap commit message bodies to 72–76 character width; everybody knows this and tools like 'git gui' usually make it clear that hard-wrapping is expected. But that doesn't seem to be the case for SVN. For example, TortoiseSVN's commit dialog gives absolutely no hint about wrapping. Does it mean that it's preferred to leave commit message unwrapped? Or should I chose my own boundary? Is there a clear authoritative guiding about that?

Comment: If you even have to think about this, you’re doing it wrong: commit messages should only be one or two sentences. Long text goes in an issue tracker or a README file.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: I'm probably wrong, but I think that the commit history ideally must be self-sufficient. Have you ever tried to migrate from one issue tracker to another one? Did you manage to keep all the issue IDs and permalinks the same after the migration?

Comment: The commit history can never be self-sufficient, because it works at the wrong level of granularity for discussing higher-level concerns (that is, a commit message describes a commit, not anything larger). That’s why we have documentation such as README files and issue trackers in the first place. As to your question, I have migrated between issue trackers, but not recently; however, it wouldn’t be too hard for a migration script to fix up links as part of the migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your organizations requirements.

If you are exporting your subversion commits for some type of document that requires a 72-76 width, then you can enforce that amongst the team (there is probably even a regular expression check you could write in a pre-commit hook that could *literally* enforce this). Otherwise, I see no need to restrict a character width (that svn doesn't automatically keep count of anyway).

However, if you're simply asking about best practices/authoritative guide to give you an answer, you won't find any. Log messages are open to interpretation and use by your team.

Comment: Nice point about the pre-commit hook. However, it's not reasonable to *expressionlessly* enforce the rule: for example, it's a common situation in Git commit messages to have long URLs unwrapped.

Comment: Exactly, and that's why it's open to interpretation. You're 100% correct. I wrote a regular expression for my organization in a hook to check to see if a certain string exist (basically `[see #310]` because there are certain repositories that we want to **make sure** are tied to a ticket every time something is changed. _That_ would be a valid reason to enforce commits to be a certain way.For your case, it's all up to you! :)

Comment: I would avoid using a pre-commit hook just to check for log message line width.

Answer (score 3):

TortoiseSVN shows a hint for wrapping the commit messages. You need to add the  [`tsvn:logwidthmarker` property](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-tsvn-props) to your repository. You can also define various log message templates.

[image]

BTW, VisualSVN Commit Selection window also supports `tsvn:logwidthmarker`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no global standard/"best practice" for this with Subversion. Do whatever works for your organization and project.